# Scenebuilder Button ID

Tags: scenebuilder

If I create a button in scenebuilder and want to use this button in my javacode, what is the ID of this button?
I've tried with writing a fx:id, lets say button1.
when trying Button button1 = new Button(); I cant access this ID, is there any possible way to do this?